# Download Gradle in FLutter run behind Proxy

Tags: flutter, http, gradle, proxy

I am doing -

```
Flutter run -v
```

[image]

downloading Gradle files is not working behind a proxy.
Any Solution???

Comment: while back so i changed flutter.gradle file like this   `buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
}`